# Continued presence of AjaxControlToolkit requests months after removing from site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

we removed all traces of the AjaxControlToolkit from our busy site probably about 6 months ago, yet we are still seeing a considerable amount of errors in our logs for:

"Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

The request is of the format:
http://www.mysite.com/WebResource.axd?d=pPyiEUtn0pvBAnLkfcFmsCBZpn10hZQ-g7SR3D8ta3UkzGvlLexhSxaX6eQlLiY6ouSNL9_ncb0xOjJNL_XOJg2&t=634159218460000000

User agent:
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)

Anyone got any ideas? Bot? Proxies? Anything to do with temp ASP.Net files hanging about on the server? A web.config line needing removal?

We're stumped...

Thanks,
Monty

Answer (score 0):

I think it is probably just an old cache for your page which is getting accessed.

Comment: I think you don't have to worry about this. It is not causing any harm, right?